# How to use SQL count(*) with dplyr?

Tags: mysql, sql, r, dplyr

The [dplyr database vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html) explains:

> "Any function that dplyr doesn’t know how to convert it leaves as is - that means if you want to use any other function that database provides, you can use it as is. "

Using the same example as in the vignette, the flights dataset:

```
library(nycflights13)
my_db <- src_sqlite("my_db.sqlite3", create = T)
flights_sqlite <- copy_to(my_db, flights, temporary = FALSE, indexes = list(
c("year", "month", "day"), "carrier", "tailnum"))
```

I managed to use count() in the tbl() creation statement:

```
tbl(my_db, sql("SELECT count(*) FROM flights"))
```

But this returns the count of the whole table only obviously, not the other columns, how could I use SQL count() after a filter operation?

Let's say that I would like to count the number of flights to Honolulu and I would like `dplyr::explain()` to return the corresponding SQL query.

```
tbl(my_db, "flights") %>% filter(dest == "HNL") %>% explain()
```

Describes the SQL statement that returns all data for flights to Honolulu. How to count these flights only?

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Comment: If you want all the rest of the columns maybe `tbl(my_db, sql("SELECT *, count(*) FROM flights"))`?

Comment: The desired output is the number of flights for a particular destination. The real desired output is the SQL statement to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
my_db %>% tbl("flights") %>% mutate( n = n())
```

Comment: Thanks it works also after a filter; `my_db %>% tbl("flights") %>% filter(dest == "HNL") %>% mutate(n = n()) %>% select(n) %>% explain()` And the SQL returned by explain is nice and short: `SELECT COUNT() AS "n" FROM "flights" WHERE "dest" = 'HNL'`

Comment: or `%>% summarize(n())` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351315/count-number-of-rows-when-using-dplyr-to-access-sql-table-query