# Count number of rows when using dplyr to access sql table/query

Tags: mysql, r, postgresql, sqlite, dplyr

What would be the efficient way to count the number of rows which using dplyr to access sql table. MWE is below using SQLite, but I use PostgreSQL and have the same issue. Basically dim() is not very consistent. I used

```
dim()
```

This works for a schema in the database (First case), but is not very consistent when I create a tbl from an SQL query for the same schema (Second case). My number of rows is in the millions or I see this even with a small 1000 of rows. I get NA or ??. Is there anything that is missing?

```
#MWE
test_db <- src_sqlite("test_db.sqlite3", create = T)
library(nycflights13)
flights_sqlite <- copy_to(test_db, flights, temporary = FALSE, indexes = list(
c("year", "month", "day"), "carrier", "tailnum"))

flights_postgres <- tbl(test_db, "flights")
```

First case (table from direct schema)

```
flights_postgres

 > flights_postgres
 Source: postgres 9.3.5 []
 From: flights [336,776 x 16]

   year month day dep_time dep_delay arr_time arr_delay carrier tailnum flight    origin dest air_time distance hour minute
  1  2013     1   1      517         2      830        11      UA  N14228   1545    EWR  IAH      227     1400    5     17
  2  2013     1   1      533         4      850        20      UA  N24211   1714    LGA  IAH      227     1416    5     33

#using dim()
> dim(flights_postgres)
[1] 336776     16
```

The above works and get the count of the number of rows.
Second case (table from SQL query)

```
 ## use the flights schema above but can also be used to create other variables (like lag, lead)   in run time
 flight_postgres_2 <- tbl(test_db, sql("SELECT * FROM flights"))

  >flight_postgres_2
 Source: postgres 9.3.5 []
 From: <derived table> [?? x 16]

  year month day dep_time dep_delay arr_time arr_delay carrier tailnum flight     origin dest air_time distance hour minute
   1  2013     1   1      517         2      830        11      UA  N14228   1545    EWR  IAH      227     1400    5     17
   2  2013     1   1      533         4      850        20      UA  N24211   1714    LGA  IAH      227     1416    5     33

> 
> dim(flight_postgres_2)
[1] NA 16
```

As you see it either prints as ?? or NA. So not very helpful.

I got around this by either using collect() or then convert the output to a dataframe using as.data.frame() to check the dimension. But these two methods may not be the ideal solution, given the time it may take for larger number of rows.

Comment: I can't get your MWE to work to test it, but I'd try `tally`, or `n` if you're within another function.

Comment: @alistaire made edits to the MWE - uses SQLite this time, but the issue is same.

Comment: `tally` works fine for me, as does `summarise(n())`

Comment: Or keep it in SQL with `tbl(test_db, sql('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flights'))` or `sqldf::sqldf('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flights')`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the answer is what @alistaire suggests: Do it in the database.

```
> flight_postgres_2 %>% summarize(n())
Source: sqlite 3.8.6 [test_db.sqlite3]
From: <derived table> [?? x 1]

      n()
    (int)
1  336776
..    ...
```

Asking `dim` to do this would be having your cake (lazy evaluation of SQL with `dplyr`, keeping data in the database) and eating it too (having full access to the data in `R`).

Note that this is doing @alistaire's approach underneath:

```
> flight_postgres_2 %>% summarize(n()) %>% explain()
<SQL>
SELECT "n()"
FROM (SELECT COUNT() AS "n()"
FROM (SELECT * FROM flights) AS "zzz11") AS "zzz13"


<PLAN>
  selectid order from                                                         detail
1        0     0    0 SCAN TABLE flights USING COVERING INDEX flights_year_month_day
```